# React Twitter Login how to response back token and token secrete

Tags: reactjs, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to implement twitter login in my React app and I need to pass oauth_token and oauth_token_secret to my backend which I will get after a successful login. but now I am only getting the code after successful login.

[image]

here my url according to their docs which will redirect user to twitter login page then redirect back to my website with respose code:

`https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${my_client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_domain}/login?twitter&scope=tweet.read%20tweet.write%20follows.read%20follows.write%20like.read%20like.write%20users.read%20offline.access&state=state&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain`

also I tried [react-twitter-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-login) but it's very outdated and throw me  NetworkError error

```
 <twitterlogin
      authcallback={authhandler}
      consumerkey={consumer_key}
      consumersecret={consumer_secret}
      callbackurl={callback_url}
    />
```

my full code:

```
  const handleSubmit = (data)=>{
      console.log(data)
              if (data == "twitter"){
              window.location.href = `https://twitter.com/i/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=${my_client_id}&redirect_uri=${redirect_domain}/login?twitter&scope=tweet.read%20tweet.write%20follows.read%20follows.write%20like.read%20like.write%20users.read%20offline.access&state=state&code_challenge=challenge&code_challenge_method=plain`
           }  
        
        }
```

**my jsx**

```
   <button type="button" onClick={()=>handleSubmit("twitter")}> Twitter Login </button>
```